# I am getting an exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Tags: java, exception

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MathsHacker {

public static int fact(int n)
{
    if(n==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return n*fact(n-1);
}
/*
    I checked for 1 test case giving an input=5277
    it results in exception :
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
*/

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int T =in.nextInt();
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < T; a0++)
    {
        int N = in.nextInt();
        if(N==1)
        {
            System.out.println("0");  
        }
        else
        {
            int res=fact(N)/(fact(N-2)*fact(2));
            System.out.println(res);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The faculty of 5277 is way too big for an int.

Comment: @TobiasGeiselmann then what should i change in my code .just change int with long?

Comment: No, `long` is also not big enough. You could use `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 2):

`5277!` is a 17354 digit number.

Rather than calculating `fact(N) / (fact(N-2) * fact(2))`, you should realize that `fact(N) / fact(N-2)` is the same as `N * (N-1)`, so if you calculate that instead, your calculation won't overflow.

Alternatively, change `fact()` to calculate using `BigInteger`, but you're really wasting time by multiplying 5277 numbers, then multiplying 5275 numbers, and dividing them, just to get a result that can be calculated by multiplying 2 numbers.

Comment: what if i had to with this way, what change can I do?

Comment: @AashishKalia Already told you: Change `fact()` to calculate using `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum number an int can hold is up to:

```
2 ^ 31 - 1 = 2,147,483,647
```

However:

```
12! = 479,001,600
13! = 6,227,020,800
```

Then, this means that after 12! you cannot hold the value in an `int`.

While error given by the compiler is not really explicit, it's an overflow

You could use `long` but that's still:

```
2 ^ 63 - 1 = 9.223372036854776e18 ~ 9,223,372,036,854,776,000
21! = 5.109094217170944e19 ~ 51,090,942,171,709,440,000
```

As you can see it still overflows...

So, a better advice would be to use [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class

Comment: And can u plzz tell me what changes I have to make in my code for it,bcz i really don't know the implementation

Comment: Read about `BigInteger` class and look for examples first, and try them yourself, then come back if you don't fully understand it (asking an specific question)

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are massively overflowing the integer range (that's what the other answers already said). The overflow in itself happens silently, just giving wrong results (clipping all binary digits in front of the trailing 32 bits).

What leads to the `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero` is that the binary representation of your `(fact(N-2)*fact(2))` with N=5277 has more than 32 trailing zeros (in fact, it must be around 4000 trailing zeroes). And clipped to the trailing 32 bits, that's zero. That's where the division by zero happens.

Comment: `5277!` has 17354 decimal digits, with 1317 trailing zeroes. It has 57648 binary digits (bits), with 5270 trailing zeroes.